# Bs4 soup output is sometimes a list object sometimes not

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Depending on whether I use the following code:

`results = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'results'})`

or

```
results = soup(class_='results')[0]('div', attrs={
    'data-_tn' : 'companies/row'})
```

I get the same html tree stored in results but the latter method is a one-dimensional array with commas separating the 'companies/row' divs. I realize this is very little context to the problem (not really a problem) but I am just trying to figure out the bs4 behind why this is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The examples you're giving aren't doing the same thing. Compare:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = '<html>' \
           '<body>' \
           '  <div>No</div>' \
           '  <div class="results">' \
           '    <div data-_tn="companies/row">Yes</div>' \
           '  </div>' \
           '</body>' \
           '</html>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

result = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'results'})
print(result)

result = soup(class_='results')[0]
print(result)
```

Note that the results are identical, each giving you a `Tag` object.

So, you can follow each by calling it, to further narrow things down:

```
result = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'results'})('div', attrs={'data-_tn': 'companies/row'})
print(result)

result = soup(class_='results')[0]('div', attrs={'data-_tn': 'companies/row'})
print(result)
```

In this case, you will get a list of matching results for both, with just one element, since there is only one match.

The method `.find()` only returns a single result, while using `.find_all()` would give you the exact same result as the second way of doing things:

```
result = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'results'})
print(result)

result = soup(class_='results')
print(result)
```

Note how I removed the `[0]` bit from the second call to `soup`, which was only there to select the first element from the returned list of results.